# Turn Off CKEditor's Auto Correct Settings

Tags: ckeditor

Does anybody know of a way to turn off CKEditor's HTML tidying function? I know CKEditor has some pretty strict HTML rewriting rules in place, but I am wondering if there is a way to control those so pages being edited don't get messed up when the HTML does not follow CKEditor's concept of valid code?

Is there a plugin to help, maybe, that can help to add exceptions?

Comment: I don't know any plugin, but you can use enclosed tags to prevent this from happening.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `config.allowedContent` in your config.js file like this:

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

Check [documentation](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-allowedContent)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer: "Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better." Thus you make your answer much more valuable and SO a better knowledge base.